# Why does invoking a method with parameters return a 404 error?

Tags: ruby, rest, ruby-grape

I'm pretty new to Ruby, I know a little bit of Sinatra but what I actually need for my app is Grape for rest api.

Working with a method with parameters at all works like a charm, but when I'm trying to add parameters I get 404 not found exception.

Where am I going wrong here? Thanks

```
        resource :devs do

        desc "Get all devs"
        get do
            authenticate!
            Dev.all
        end

        desc "Get dev by email"
        params do
            requires :email, type: String, desc: "Dev's email"
        end
        route_param :email do
            get  do
                authenticate!
                @devs = Dev.all(:email == params[:email])
                #!error('email not found', 204) unless @devs.length > 0
            end
        end

        desc "Get dev by API key"
        get :key do
            authenticate!
            @dev = Dev.first(:api_key == params[:key])

            !error('email not found', 204) unless @devs.length > 0
        end
    end
```

This is the call I make in PostMan (I also added the header for Apikey there)

```
localhost:9292/devs/email/orelzion@gmail.com
```

But it always give me the same result 404

Comment: Call should be `localhost:9292/devs?email=orelzion@gmail.com`

Comment: Thank you, but if I'm doing this it will just ignore the parameter and will go to the root funtion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `route_param` directive doesn't work the way you think it does. Given the code you posted, the link you should be visiting is `localhost:9292/devs/orelzion@gmail.com`.

If you want the code to match the URL you wrote instead, use a nested namespace (or equivalently, a nested resource):

```
resource :devs do
  ...

  namespace :email do
    desc "Get dev by email"
    params do
      requires :email, type: String, desc: "Dev's email"
    end
    route_param :email do
      get do
      ...
      end
    end
  end

  ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed what I needed was the right call